# Suppress Repeating values in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I'm using Oracle BIPublisher to build a sql query. Right now my query output is:

```
ControlID  Role
1          ABC
1          SJD
1          DKF
2          LLL
2          IJK
```

How do I write the sql so that the output comes out like this?

```
ControlID  Role   
1          ABC
           SJD
           DKF
2          LLL
           IJK
```

*** Edit:
I was able to suppress using Tim's solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GRCC_CONTROL_ID  ORDER BY erp_user_name) = 1
         THEN GRCC_CONTROL_ID  ELSE NULL END AS GRCC_CONTROL_ID ,
    ,role
from GRC_CTRL_AAC_INCIDENTS 
ORDER BY GRCC_CONTROL_ID, role
```

I want to replace the control_id with the actual control name but that is in a separate table. When I replace c.name in the above query, I get an error that says

> 'FROM' keyword not found where expected

:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.name  ORDER BY role) = 1
         THEN c.name  ELSE NULL END AS c.name ,
    role
from GRC_CTRL_AAC_INCIDENTS 
,GRC_CTRL_CCM_CONTROL_TL c
where GRCC_CONTROL_ID = c.id
ORDER BY c.name, role
```

Comment: If the order of rows is essential we need  an ordering column. Otherwise the order `ABC`, `SJD`, `DKF` can not be guaranteed.

Comment: Wrong syntax `.. AS c.name`, must be `AS name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a presentation requirement, and so might be best handled in your presentation layer (e.g. something like PHP or Java).  That being said, we could handle this using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ControlID ORDER BY Role) = 1
         THEN ControlID ELSE NULL END AS ControlID,
    t.Role
FROM yourTable t
ORDER BY
    t.ControlID,
    t.Role;
```

[image]

### Demo

**Edit:**

You are using the old style pre ANSI-92 join syntax is your actual updated query attempt.  Don't do that.  Instead, use an explicit join, with aliases:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY role) = 1
         THEN c.name ELSE NULL END AS name,  -- NOT c.name
    role
FROM GRC_CTRL_AAC_INCIDENTS t
INNER JOIN GRC_CTRL_CCM_CONTROL_TL c
    ON t.GRCC_CONTROL_ID = c.id
ORDER BY
    c.name,
    role;
```

Comment: @Hailey This is not a good way to get help on this site.  Please _delete_ your comment, and instead either update your original question or leave a more focused comment which mentions I problem I can understand based on the information you have given us.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Tim, I have updated the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to attempt to answer your end goal.

With the approach you are taking, it's going to be difficult to display the data correctly by not exposing the controlID in the XML. If the ControlID is not coming over in the XML, you wont be able to group the roles together with others in the same ControlID on the report. Role SJD has the same ControlID as LLL.

This is a good time to use the "regrouping" or "for-each-group" functionality in BI Publisher.

```
<?for-each-group: BASE-GROUP;GROUPING-ELEMENT?>
```

Assuming these are two elements are in a `ROW` element:

```
<?for-each-group: ROW;ControlID?>
<?sort:ControlID?>
<?ControlID?>
<?for-each:current-group()?>
<?sort:Role?>
<?Role?>
<?end for-each?>
<?end for-each-group?>
```

You could easily add this to repeating table rows, and use a nested table for the inner for-each.

There's quite a bit of additional documentation and examples on the internet for BI Publisher regrouping functionality.

Answer (score 0):

this used to work

Break on GRCC_CONTROL_ID

Comment: If it used to work, then it no longer works now? If so, why post it here?